# How do I install the nlohmann json library into visual studios (C++)?

Tags: c++, json

Hello stack overflow community, I just want to know how to install this library https://github.com/nlohmann/json, as well as any other libraries I might want to install from github.

Comment: Searching for "How to install library in visual studio?" gave me 960 questions, possibly including yours. Please do a bit of research up front! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I did a bit of research, but what I tried didn’t work.

Comment: So without any context about what you did or what went wrong, you are just going to get told the same things again, which will go wrong in the same way again.